# Replace Woocommerce "add to cart" to be "Download" button

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a Wordprees website and I sell book (product ID 769) on my site, I want woocommerce replace "add to cart" button with "Download" button if

- user is logged in
- and purchased (product ID "769")

user will find "download" button instant of "add to cart" button in product single page

Comment: You might be better of taking this question to the WooCommerce Slack community as community members here consider WooCommerce to be off topic. Then again, you might get answers here too.

Answer (score 2):

1. hook into the woocommerce hook is_purchasable

   ```
    add_filter("woocommerce_is_purchasable", function($product, $isPurchasable)
    {
        if(!$isPurchasable)
            return $isPurchasable;

        $productId = $product->get_id();
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if($user->exists() && $productId == 769)
        {
            $userId = $user->ID;
            $userEmail = $user->user_email;

            if(wc_customer_bought_product($userEmail, $userId, $productId))
            {
                //block the purchase so the user sees read more instead of add to cart
                $isPurchasable = false;
            }
        }

        return $isPurchasable;
    });
   ```
2. hook into the init field and and if the current page is that product id
   then we will need to display:none the add to cart button and instead add a download
   button. If you have access to a theme builder add a button on the single product and
   hide it in the beginning. That will make this process much easier.

   ```
    add_action("init", function()
    {
        global $product;
        if(is_product() && $product->get_id() == 769)
        {
            $className = "add_to_cart_button";
            $downloadLink = ""; // your link here

            printf(
                "<script>
                     let element = document.getElementByClassName(\"%s\");
                     element.style.display=\"none\";

                     let link = document.createElement(\"a\");
                     link.classList.add(\"button\");
                     link.setAttribute(\"href\", \"%s\");
                     link.textContent = \"download\";

                     let parent = element.parentElement;
                     parent.insertAdjacentElement(\"afterend\", link);
                 </script>",
                 $className,
                 $downloadLink
            );
        }
    });
   ```

ps: If you want the user to be logged in before adding the item to cart do the following

```
    add_filter("woocommerce_is_purchasable", function($product, $isPurchasable)
    {
        if(!$isPurchasable)
            return $isPurchasable;

        $productId = $product->get_id();
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        //block the user from even adding it to cart before logging in
        if($productId == 769 && !$user->exists())
            return false;

        if($user->exists() && $productId == 769)
        {
            $userId = $user->ID;
            $userEmail = $user->user_email;

            if(wc_customer_bought_product($userEmail, $userId, $productId))
            {
                //block the purchase so the user sees read more instead of add to cart
                $isPurchasable = false;
            }
        }

        return $isPurchasable;
    });
```

ps2: I did not run this code myself just off the top of my head. Should be close enough though to run. will check if it runs on my system.

New Code: Just did a test run and it works

```
            add_filter("woocommerce_is_purchasable", function($isPurchasable, $product)
            {
                if(!$isPurchasable)
                    return $isPurchasable;

                $productId = $product->get_id();
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                if($user->exists() && $productId == 796)
                {
                    $userId = $user->ID;
                    $userEmail = $user->user_email;

                    if(wc_customer_bought_product($userEmail, $userId, $productId))
                    {
                        //block the purchase so the user sees read more instead of add to cart
                        $isPurchasable = false;
                    }
                }

                return $isPurchasable;
            }, 10, 2);

            add_filter("woocommerce_is_purchasable", function($isPurchasable, $product)
            {
                if(!$isPurchasable)
                    return $isPurchasable;

                $productId = $product->get_id();
                $user = wp_get_current_user();

                //dont allow non existing users to buy
                if(!$user->exists() && $productId == 796)
                    $isPurchasable = false;

                return $isPurchasable;
            }, 10, 2);

            add_action("woocommerce_after_single_product", function()
            {
                global $post;
                $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
                
                if(empty($product) || is_null($product))
                    return;

                if($product->get_id() != 796)
                    return;

                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                if(!$user->exists())
                    return;

                if(!wc_customer_bought_product($user->user_email, $user->ID, $product->get_id()))
                    return;

                $productId = $product->get_id();
                $downloadLink = "#"; // your link here

                echo sprintf(
                    "<script>
                        let element = document.getElementById(\"product-%d\");
                        let form = element.getElementsByTagName(\"form\")[0];
                        let addToCartButton = form.getElementsByTagName(\"button\")[0];

                        element = addToCartButton;
                        let classList = element.classList;

                        element.style.display=\"none\";

                        let link = document.createElement(\"a\");
                        link.classList = classList;
                        link.setAttribute(\"href\", \"%s\");
                        link.textContent = \"download\";

                        let parent = element.parentElement;
                        parent.insertAdjacentElement(\"afterend\", link);
                    </script>",
                    $productId,
                    $downloadLink
                );
            });
```